# Cannot read property 'module' of undefined while building angular lib

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I am converting an angular app to angular lib. I generated angular lib project and slowly moving the modules. I now get the following error while building the library.

> ng build lib

Error

```
Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at MetadataBundler.convertSymbol (C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:312:61)
    at createReference (C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:438:27)
    at MetadataBundler.convertReference (C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:486:28)
    at MetadataBundler.convertExpression (C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:415:37)
    at C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:364:79
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MetadataBundler.convertMember (C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:364:47)
    at C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:349:70
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MetadataBundler.convertMembers (C:\Code\abc\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:349:38)
```

Typically this error is caused when trying to register dependencies incorrectly in the module. How can I find, which part of my configuration makes this exception?

It works fine in angular app.

Comment: Did you use `ng generate library my-lib` first?

Comment: yes. I generated the library first and it was building fine.

Comment: can you try the `--watch` flag?

Comment: Also try the `--buildEventLog=buildEventLog`  option

Comment: --buildEventLog=buildEventLog doesn't provide any helpful information.

Comment: need to see your modules really. do you maybe have inter-dependencies between library modules?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If angular decides to fail on aot compilation, you could try to go into `node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js` and do some console logging in that file.
I would start from placing console.log in convertSymbol function.
[image]
That should provide you with some information about the file path which angular cli used before falling on module compilation.
For example in my case, it was the re-export of the constant from the barrel which broke the compilation
[image]
So finding all the usages of TWO_FA_INITIAL_STATE, and directly importing TWO_FA_INITIAL_STATE, fixed that particular problem.

Comment: This was really helpful. In my case, I had an API module that was being generated from Swagger, but that I wasn't importing into my component module.

Answer (score 3):

I've just hit this problem with the following file structure:

```
components/component-n/component-n.component.ts
components/index.ts
my-module.ts
```

Where `components/index.ts` contains:

```js
export { ComponentN } from './component-n/component-n.component.ts';
```

And `my-module.ts` contains:

```js
import { ComponentN } from './components';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  declarations: [
    ComponentN
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Turns out the Angular compiler can't cope with this and throws the "Cannot read property 'module' of undefined" error.

Changing `my-module.ts` to import directly from `components/component-n/component-n.component.ts` instead, and deleting the `index.ts`, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I  forgot to export a particular file in my public-api.ts. The file in question was basically a module root, simply re-exporting  other files from the module.

When I tried to import a symbol from said file, it would give me this error (but not even a call stack).

It's really quite strange, but adding said file to public-api.ts fixed the issue (I say it's strange because I was not importing above mentioned symbol from public-api.ts in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

for a library project make sure you export your classes in the `public-api.ts` file

`export * from './lib/classes/index';`